# Error inflating class fragment mapfragment v2

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am getting below error in **Android 4.4.4 it is crashing, but it is working  perfectly in Andriod 5.0.1**

I am loading Map by below Java Class

```
public class MapActivity extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    double longitude, latitude;
    TextView m_tvNo, m_tvYes;
    public static String m_Name, m_Location;
    DBParse m_DBparser;
    Context m_cont;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    Circle mapCircle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_search_location_dialog_map); <<----in this line I am getting an error
```

Below is XML Code

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/map_height" />
```

I am getting below error

```
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101): Process: com.example.achessapp, PID: 20101
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.achessapp/com.example.achessapp.fragment.settting.highrisk.map.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2439)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5633)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1997)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at com.example.achessapp.fragment.settting.highrisk.map.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:57)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    ... 11 more
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment did not create a view.
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4890)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
04-02 19:22:01.425: E/AndroidRuntime(20101):    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Extends it by

> public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

you have extended it as Activity only

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by just putting **super** on first

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_search_location_dialog_map);
```